# Photoshop shows sort of Inner Shadow on Images by Default

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm having issues with Photoshop CC (CS6), when I create a any type of document Photoshop seems to have a little Inner Shadow on the left and right sections of the template/image.

I though it might of just been something there for the editing part but when I save the project as any type of image (jpg, png, exc.) it still displays the same black lines. Does anyone know what might be wrong with my Photoshop?

[image]

[image]

Still displaying the lines, 
[image]

Comment: Screenshot your layer panel and add it to your question using the edit function

Comment: Kind of looks like the canvas drop shadow setting in the preferences, but that shouldn't save with the image.

Comment: My hunch is it's a peculiarity of your monitor, because it appears to be limited to the vertical edges. This would also explain why nobody has successfully answered your question - because nobody else can see it.

You could verify as much by noting what happens when you zoom in. Does the perceived inner shadow get larger along with the other artwork? Or does it stay the same size?

What happens with a lighter interface colour, or with lighter artwork? Is the effect still there?

Comment: (continued) You could also try viewing the image within a different app (to rule out Photoshop) or on a different monitor (although if the second monitor had the same problem, this won't tell us much).

Let us know how you go.

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is a shadow that Photoshop puts around the canvas when you're in certain view modes.
To turn it off:

- Go to Photoshop->Preferences->Interface
- Change all Border settings under Appearance to None

[image]

Now you won't see the black line.

Comment: @Circle_B I tried this and didn't seem to fix the issue, added another screenshot.

Comment: @Prosperity Err seem to me it did, you can clearly see in the screenshot the drop shadow is now gone. Anyway you may want to share the psd file. Anyway it is possible the background does not span the entire image.

Comment: @Prosperity I'm not seeing any lines, can you give us a link to the psd?